# Returning values based on letters in a string using Python 2.7

Tags: string, python-2.7, contains

I'm attempting to return a specific value if certain letters (though not the exact word) is found. Starting with:

```
data = {'ANIMAL':['LION', 'BLACK BEAR', 'BROWN BEAR']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
    ANIMAL
0   LION
1   BLACK BEAR
2   BROWN BEAR
```

At first when 'BEAR' is found, Python correctly returns the '30'.

```
df['FOOD PER DAY (KG)'] = df['ANIMAL'].str.contains('BEAR') 
df['FOOD PER DAY (KG)'] = df['FOOD PER DAY (KG)'].map({True: '30', False: ''})
df
    ANIMAL      FOOD PER DAY (KG)
0   LION    
1   BLACK BEAR  30
2   BROWN BEAR  30
```

Unfortunately when 'LION' is found the False: '' overwrites the '30's identified earlier.

```
df['FOOD PER DAY (KG)'] = df['ANIMAL'].str.contains('LION') 
df['FOOD PER DAY (KG)'] = df['FOOD PER DAY (KG)'].map({True: '20', False: ''})
df
    ANIMAL      FOOD PER DAY (KG)
0   LION        20
1   BLACK BEAR  
2   BROWN BEAR
```

Is there a way to make this return:

```
    ANIMAL      FOOD PER DAY (KG)
0   LION        20
1   BLACK BEAR  30
2   BROWN BEAR  30
```

Thanks. FYI, this isn't actually for animals.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, A2A.
Okay, let's go and observe where the pit hole is.!
After the first operation:-

**Checking**

- all the True values in the FOOD PER DAY (KG)  will be replaced by 30 and
- all the False values in the field  FOOD PER DAY (KG) be replaced by ' '

So far the output is:

```
   ANIMAL       FOOD PER DAY (KG)
0  LION                  
1  BLACK BEAR                30
2  BROWN BEAR                30
```

For the second operation:-

**Checking**

- **ALL** the True values in the field FOOD PER DAY (KG) will be replaced by 20 and
- **ALL** the False values in the field FOOD PER DAY (KG) will be replaced by ' '  `we will change here`

So the point is just to update `False:' ' with False='30'`

```
  ANIMAL        FOOD PER DAY (KG)
0  LION                      20
1  BLACK BEAR                30
2  BROWN BEAR                30
```

Finally the total code would be:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'ANIMAL':['LION', 'BLACK BEAR', 'BROWN BEAR']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['FOOD PER DAY (KG)'] = df['ANIMAL'].str.contains('BEAR') 
df['FOOD PER DAY (KG)'] = df['FOOD PER DAY (KG)'].map({True: '30', False: ''})
print(df)  #Observe output so far
df['FOOD PER DAY (KG)'] = df['ANIMAL'].str.contains('LION') 
df['FOOD PER DAY (KG)'] = df['FOOD PER DAY (KG)'].map({True: '20', False:'30'})
print(df)   #Required output
```

Happy Coding..!!

Comment: Still struggling w/ this. I removed `, False: ''` in the two locations above. Now I have `Nan, 30, 30` as output, not the `20, 30, 30` needed. Any other ideas?

Comment: @TimothyGeiser My bad bro... Updated the answer please check once.